# How do i make a void method know what type to use?

Tags: c++, void

So my question is very simple but i can't find how to do it .
I created this method on **.cpp**

```cpp
void Message_Test::Integers(const uint64_t &_value){}
```

and in the **.hpp**

```cpp
void Integers(const uint64_t &_value)
```

I'm passing a `uint64_t value { 35000 }` to the method like so `Integers(value)`, but i also would like to use this method with a `uint16_t value { 35000 }`, without having to create multiple methods.

I would like to know if there is a way to change my entire parameter so it knows if its a uint64_t or a 32,16,etc ...

Comment: I'm pretty sure a 16-bit integer is implicitly convertible to a 64-bit integer. And if it isn't, you can explicitly convert it. So what's the problem?

Comment: why does it matter if the parameter is `uint64_t` or `uint16_t` ?

Comment: Do you know what templates are, and how to use them?

Comment: Are you sure you want to pass the value by reference? Unless you need to store the value for later read access in a pointer member variable, you could simply use `uint64_t` as parameter type.

Comment: @NicolBolas It's a const reference. Calling it with an `uint16_t` will create a temporary `uint64_t` and pass the address of that to the function. At the end of the function call the temporary goes out of scope and the reference becomes invalid.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik someone told me to use them but i forgot how to do it. Let me try to find some examples. Thanks!

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number it matters because I'm converting those uint and storing them in a string so i can send a message.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: So what? The function can't store that reference or its address anywhere since it might already be a temporary. Also, it's an *integer*; it takes up the same size as an address. Just copy it.

Comment: templates is one of the most advanced parts of C++. One cannot fully learn them, and use them correctly simply by finding "some examples". A C++ textbook, with a detailed, step by step guide for using templates is essential.

Comment: @NicolBolas The only point of passing it by reference would be to store it, with all the risks that involves. Otherwise, as you say, just pass by value.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Templates are not particularly advanced C++.

Comment: you can convert them all as `unint64_t`. Does it really matter what type it is? Perhaps if you post the implementation it will be easier to help. Please read about [mcve]

Comment: I wish C++ had 2 types of const references: One to say *"I just don't want to pay for copying this"* and the other for *"I need a reference to the callers object for later use and I promise not to modify it"*. Only one of those cases can handle temporaries.

Comment: @NicolBolas - an you direct me to any part of the C++ standard that describes some core section of C++ (apart from the libraries), and that's longer than the 83 pages that it takes to define templates (C++20).

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: The latter circumstance is highly dangerous, as the code that's using the reference has no way to ensure that the reference remains valid. We invented smart pointers to avoid such ownership issues.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: The *entirety* of templates is complicated. But a basic template function isn't. You don't have to learn the *entirety* of expression semantics to know what `a + b` does. You don't have to learn the *entirety* of declarations to know how `int c = 5;` works. So why should you have to learn everything about templates before you can use anything to do with them?

Comment: Sam wasn't basing his "most complicated" statement on number of pages. I say this with confidence because I don't want to live in a world where somebody keeps an ordered list of C++ section lengths in their head. He was basing it on some ephemeral quality, and then trying to use page length as a proxy. I agree that templates are not as easy as say, arithmetic operators. But in this case it's, *"You know how you have a separate `void foo(int64_t)` and a `void foo(int16_t)`? What if the language could do that FOR YOU?"*

Comment: Why are you passing your parameter by reference?  This just introduces potential complications and is less efficient here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Given that you want a `const` reference, assuming you had a good reason for it to be a reference, you can not allow any implicit conversion to happen. If the function is called with an `uint16_t` the compiler will create a temporary `uint64_t` and pass the address of that. For any valid reason to use a reference to a primitive type this would be fatal.

I don't think you have any other choice than use a template

```
template <typename T>
void Integers(const T &_value){ ... }
```

Note that the template must be in the header.

When you store the value reference somewhere for later use (That's why it's a reference, right? Because otherwise just pass by value.) you then have to figure out how to store it, e.g. with `std::variant`. Or template the whole class. Depends on the context.

Comment: "*When you store the value reference somewhere for later use*" By taking a `const&`, the function can be given references to temporaries. Storing such a reference is *inherently dangerous* regardless of implicit conversions. Thus, no function which takes a parameter by `const&` should ever store it.

Comment: Yup, that helped!

Comment: @NicolBolas So you rather take it as non-const reference to eliminate temporaries? But then the compiler must assume the function changes the value. That pessimizes your code. I agree that it is *inherently dangerous* but I don't see a 0 cost abstraction to work around it.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: "*But then the compiler must assume the function changes the value. That pessimizes your code.*" The compiler cannot assume that a `const&`'s value is always the same *anyway*, since its source may not be a `const` object. That is, a `const&` means *you* will not change it, not that it will never be changed.

Comment: @NicolBolas I was referring to the caller. When you call a function with a const reference the compiler knows it will not be changed. So it can keep using data it read into registers from the variable across function calls.